# Updating multiple rows with different values in one query

Tags: mysql, update

I am trying to understand how to UPDATE multiple rows with different values and I just don't get it. The solution is everywhere but to me it looks difficult to understand.

For instance, two updates into 1 query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET fruit='orange', drink='water', food='pizza' WHERE id=1;

UPDATE mytable SET fruit='strawberry', drink='wine', food='fish' WHERE id=2;
```

I don't understand what the CASE WHEN .. THEN ... END works and how to use it.

Wonder if someone could help me on this.

Comment: Related for sqlite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563869/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-in-a-single-sql-query

Answer (score 15):

```
UPDATE mytable SET
    fruit = CASE WHEN id=1 THEN 'orange' ELSE 'strawberry' END,
    drink = CASE WHEN id=1 THEN 'water'  ELSE 'wine'       END,
    food  = CASE WHEN id=1 THEN 'pizza'  ELSE 'fish'       END
WHERE id IN (1,2);
```

Personally, using `CASE WHEN THEN END` looks clumsy.

You could code this using the [**IF function**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if).

```
UPDATE mytable SET
    fruit = IF(id=1,'orange','strawberry'),
    drink = IF(id=1,'water','wine'),
    food  = IF(id=1,'pizza','fish')
WHERE id IN (1,2);
```

**Give it a Try !!!**

CAVEAT : `CASE WHEN THEN END` is only handy when dealing with multiple values (more than 2)

Comment: Nice, I didn't knew about this IF function. Can you just explain: = IF(id=1, 
   
Why do you need this ?

Comment: can i use this for updating around 100k records in sinle query ?

Answer (score 7):

## [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

You will need to write very complicated conditions if you want to update more than two rows. In such a case you can use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` approach.

```
INSERT into `mytable` (id, fruit, drink, food)
VALUES
    (1, 'orange', 'water', 'pizza'),
    (2, 'strawberry', 'wine', 'fish'),
    (3, 'peach', 'jiuce', 'cake')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    fruit = VALUES(fruit), 
    drink = VALUES(drink), 
    food = VALUES(food);
```

Comment: Note that this increases the autoincrement value for the table, if you're using autoincrement. For high throughput tables that might be undesirable. More info https://stackoverflow.com/a/23517191/2560641

Comment: One issue with `ON CONFLICT` is that it doesn't work if you want to omit a `NOT NULL` column that doesn't need updating: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816629/on-conflict-do-nothing-in-postgres-with-a-not-null-constraint

Comment: @CiroSantilliOurBigBook.com AFAIK there are no `ON CONFLICT` feature in MySQL

Comment: My brain JOINed both. Does `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` work with NULL constraint BTW on MySQL?